# razor script MVC 3 to render decimal numbers to whole number for decimals with zero fractions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, integer, decimal

razor script MVC 3 to render decimal numbers to whole number for decimals with zero fractions

like 300.00 to 300 
 and 39.09 as 39.09

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Model.Blah` is a `Decimal` property on the model used by your view:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Model.Blah) == Model.Blah)
{ 
    <p>@Model.Blah.ToString("N0")</p> 
} else {
    <p>@Model.Blah.ToString("N2")</p>
}
```